# ajax callback as php class method with namespace

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, namespaces

When I use a class method for ajax callback I get a server error. I suppose PHP namespaces (for a composer autoloader) are the reason because when I used strictly `require` instead of `use` it worked fine.
Here is my ajax call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type:'POST',
  url:'AjaxHandler.php',
  data:'SSN='+value,
  success:function(response){},
  error: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

AjaxHandler.php:

```
<?php
  use My\Service\FormAction;
  FormAction::handleForm();
```

JS file and AjaxHandler.php are in public folder which is in a global namespace.

Maybe someone could write simple example hot to call class methods with namespaces as ajax callback.

Comment: How you call the composer autoloader file ?

Comment: @miglio I call it in the top of index.php file. Then goes simple html  `<!DOCTYPE html>...`  with js requiring.

Comment: It is called the [spl autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php). The `$class` variable in its first arguement has the entire class, in your case `My\Service\FormAction`. Explode and require the needed file. Simple as that. Now get your hands dirty and write it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@miglio was right when asked the question. I set my autoload requiring to the AjaxHandler.php and used full namespace for method `\My\Service\FormAction::handleForm();`
Thnx to everyone!